# Look for today's date in Google new's results

Tags: python

I want to fetch data from the most recent article in Google news

I am starting off using datetime package in Python and would like to format today's date

```
from datetime import date

today =date.today()
print(today)

>> 2016-12-10
```

To the following format:

```
December 10
```

It is necessary that "December" is put as a string and "10" as an integer in order to to loop

```
December 10
December 9
December 8
December 7
```

Until the date matches the Google results

```
import requests
link = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1535&bih=799&tbm=nws&q=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&oq=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&gs_l=serp.3...1632004.1638057.0.1638325.24.24.0.0.0.0.257.2605.0j15j2.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.0.0.Nl4BZQWwR3o"

fetch_data =requests.get(link)

content = str((fetch_data.content))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a list containing each month as a string and then use `today.month` and `today.day` to get the needed numbers.

```
from datetime import date
Months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
today = date.today()
print("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],today.day))
```

Note: `today.day` is an integer by default just like `today.month`